# Not able to install package https://github.com/zackslash/php-web-article-extractor

Tags: php, web-scraping, composer-php

The setup is already done in one of the earlier servers but not able to setup as the git repo is not visible.
This is a php library to extract web content.

Could there be any other method of setting this package?
OR is it possible to copy the setup from older server? (If yes how?)